# Some link are not showing in the Inspect section but they are hyperlinked in web

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why some links are showing in Chrome but not in the Inspect...While I scrape some href (links) in Facebook using Selenium, it only gives "#" as the output but it has links on it.

So I checked the web at the initial loading it have only href = "#", And then I hover the mouse to that point, and suddenly the link popped out there as this

> href="https://www.facebook.com/clubxuk/posts/pfbid02pSWMDTqCmnbsRdvVmjJtu6wjpiU8H6PMzWtRBRyjkZuEWgkBd1frQ5ULkDXhtZJal_cft__[0]=AZXXKgjIkzes1WPDHK_rIRkJQjmIopINGlK4pcyT7n2NE5_0AjTn9m77PFEQ1uMaghvqVg6P0DR9Eu9Y0_c7WHY-peLuzsbZ9A81is8l8qMoZkYO4f_bBeSTqvB6XC9pVO0&**tn**=%2CO%2CP-R".

Comment: oup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')


anchors = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x1heor9g xt0b8zv xo1l8bm'})

anchors


[<a class="x1i10hfl xjbqb8w x6umtig x1b1mbwd xaqea5y xav7gou x9f619 x1ypdohk xt0psk2 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r xexx8yu x4uap5 x18d9i69 xkhd6sd x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x1heor9g xt0b8zv xo1l8bm" href="#" role="link" tabindex="0">

Comment: Don't add comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. Use code blocks to prevent formatting issues. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**Lazy loading**

Lazy loading is a strategy to identify resources as non-blocking (non-critical) and load these only when needed. It's a way to shorten the length of the critical rendering path, which translates into reduced page load times.

Lazy loading can occur on different moments in the application, but it typically happens on some user interactions such as scrolling and navigation.

A hash - `#` within a hyperlink specifies an HTML element id to which the window should be scrolled or raise an event in the javascript code.
href="#some-id" would scroll to an element on the current page such as .

href="//site.example/#some-id" would go to site.example and scroll to the id on that page.